How to get an estimate when a job is going to start accoriding to current schedule?
I want to find out when my jobs are going to start. According to the docs it should be possible with squeue --start, however the start times seem to be N/A until the job starts, and it also is just a date. I would like to get an estimate, according to the current state of the queue, in how many minutes/hours/days is my job going to be executed using SLURM.

Is there a wall time limit defined by default?
